# "Here it comes". and " There she is." What do they mean? Where are they used? I don't know how to use it

Tags: word-usage

"Here it comes". and " There she is." What do they mean?
Where are they used? I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

### Context is important

These are some examples of how those statements might be used:

### Give notice of something (it) or someone (she) approaching/arriving.

> **John**: Where's the train?
>
> **Robert**: Here it comes.

or

> **John**: Where's the dog?
>
> **Robert**: There she is.

However, in English (and I'm sure other languages) we anthropomorphize inanimate objects (particularly vehicles) and talk to or about them as if they were living things. Therefore, you will also hear things like this:

> **John**: Where's the boat?
>
> **Robert**: There she is.

### Forewarn (snidely) of another person talking:

> **John**: Robert, your wife is here looking for you. She doesn't look happy.
>
> **Robert**: Here it comes.

"It" refers not to the wife but to the angry tirade that she is about to say to Robert.

But you could also hear an exchange like this:

> **John**: Robert, your wife is here looking for you. She doesn't look happy.
>
> **Eric**: Here she comes.
>
> **Robert**: Here *it* comes.

Robert's remark has multiple, equally valid meanings. He may mean to shift the focus from the approaching wife to the tirade she will give **or** he could be implying that his wife is an "it" (something not human). The ambiguity produces humor and you'll often hear exchanges like this on sitcom shows.